# cannot stop mouse event propagation

Tags: javascript, events, html

EDIT:  here is a jsfiddle -- notice what happens when you grab the center resize bar and slide it left -- for some reason the text content in the left div gets selected, even though I call stopPropagation() in the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/2Dayx/4/  [**Errant text content selecting problem fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dayx/4/)

I've successfully handled mouse propagations before but this is a bit unusual.  I have a 2-pane window and a vertical slider bar in between them (the vertical slider bar is just a thin vertical div that responds to mouse events).

The unusual bit is -- when the user clicks the mouse down on the center slider div -- I need to get the document to inform me of the mouse move events so that I can:

1) move the slider bar to the left or right, depending on the mouse direction, and...

2) adjust the widths of the left and right divs based on the mouse position

So when I detect the user clicking on the divider div -- I set the document's 'mousemove' and 'mouseup' handlers to my 2 functions, **moveDivider()** and **endDividerMove()** (code below).

The sliding panel-size-adjusting div, and the left and right panels resizing as the user adjusts the slider -- that works fine.  I can click on the divider div that splits the left half and right half of the window, and move the divider to change the size of the left and right sides.

The problem is the text content in my 2 divs is getting **selected**, ie. **highlighted** as the mouse moves.  I can't figure out why, because I call **event.stopPropagation()** at the very top of the mouse move handler.  I need to **not** be selecting any content as the center adjuster bar is being moved, left or rightward, to adjust the left and right panel sizes.

When the panel size adjuster bar is moved, it's as if the text content in my divs is getting those mouse move events, *even though* I stop propagation.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

<script>

 var trackDivider = false;

 function readyDividerMove(event)
 {
     //alert("readyDividerMove(), event is: " + event);
     trackDivider = true;

     document.onmousemove = moveDivider;
     document.onmouseup = endDividerMove;


     // ATTEMPT TO STOP THE 'DRAG-SELECT' OF THE MOUSE -- no help.
     event.stopPropagation();
}



function endDividerMove(event)
{
    trackDivider = false;      
    document.onmousemove = null;      
    document.onmouseup = null;      
}

function moveDivider(event)
{
      if(trackDivider == false)
        return;

      var clientWidth = window.innerWidth;
      var leftClickX = event.clientX; 


      var leftSide = (((leftClickX / clientWidth) * 100)) + "%";
      var rightPortion = (((clientWidth - leftClickX) / clientWidth) * 100) - 0.1;

     if(leftSide < 0 || rightPortion > 99.9 || ((event.clientX + 50) > clientWidth))
        return;

     var rightSide = rightPortion + "%";
     document.getElementById('leftSide').style.width = leftSide;
     document.getElementById('rightSideStuff').style.width = rightSide;
  }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='wholepagediv' style="width: 700px; height: 500px;
      border: 3px solid green; white-space: nowrap;">
 <div id="leftSide" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; 
    width: 250px; overflow-x: hidden">
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
   <div> HELLO THIS IS A TEST </div>  
 </div>
 <div id="midPageAdjustBar" style="width: 8px; height: 99%; margin: -4px;
     display: inline-block; cursor: w-resize; vertical-align: top;
     background-color: orange; border: 2px solid red" 
     onmousedown="readyDividerMove(event)">
 </div>
 <div id="rightSideStuff" style="display: inline-block; background-color: lightblue; height: 100%">
     SOME OTHER CONTENT ON  THE RIGHT SIDE
 </div>
```

I'm wondering if the document is somehow passing the mouse moves to all the divs on the panels and **only then** invoking my moveDivider() function that adjusts the size of the panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the function call "preventDefault()" after a fair chunk of seeking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't take care about the horizontal scrollbar, so your clientWidth is wrong.

Replace 'window.innerWidth' by 'document.body.scrollWidth' and it will works :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying, no that 'jump-to-the-right' you were seeing in the original jsfiddle was an artifact I believe of the 4-panel jsfiddle layout.  The bottom-right jsfiddle window, the 'results' window, is one of four quadrants, while on my actual home page, the window.innerWidth works fine -- because on the actual page -- which is not in just one quadrant of a browser window -- on the actual page, there is no 'jumpiness' to the movement of the center slider bar that you see in the jsfiddle.  However I updated the fiddle -- but still the text in the left side gets selected. Bummer.